# Is it possible to save a local file to a different location in the same computer using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a file named `file.pdf` in my root directory along with my `index.html` page, Is there any way I can open a file dialogue manager using `<input id="savefile" type="file">` and save `file.pdf` in a different location on the same system. I know that modern browsers will not give the full path due to security issue. Is there a way to do this with JavaScript and html?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean here. If you're trying to automatically download a file (`file.pdf`) from the server to a *specific* folder on the client machine, then no, that's not possible. If that's not what you mean can you please edit the question to contain a much more clear use case.

Comment: its simpliy moving a file from `C` drive to `D` drive in the same system.

Comment: Also not possible I'm afraid. JS running in the browser cannot access the local file system for security reasons.

Comment: If you're determined on using JS and HTML you can look into creating an Electron app to do this.

Comment: This is not possible with browser JS run time engine. Node.js is a JS run time environment in which this is possible with `fs` module.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

JavaScript runs on client side and it’s scope doesn't allows you to modify any files directly.

Comment: It is possible if you give the browser permission to modify a directory using the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).